# GLSL getting location of fragment on screen

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I am trying to access the fragments position within the viewport in a fragment shader with GLSL 1.00, with 3.30 I was able to do this by passing "vec2(gl_MultiTexCoord0);" as a varying from the vertex shader to the fragment shader. Does anyone know if its possible to do this?

Comment: I have to ask... what do you need this for?

Comment: GLSL 1.00? Are you sure? AFAIK it started at version 1.10: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language#Versions

Comment: @vesan it's for an iOS app. Can't say exactly what it does. I'm probably trying to do this in a less than optimal way though lol.

Comment: @glampert glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION); returns "OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00"... maybe that's just because its in the iOS simulator??

Comment: Yes, nevermind. You are using OpenGL ES. The ES shading language starts at 1.0, as was noted by @derhass in his reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things are worth noting here:

1. You can use the same principle with GLSL3.30. The `varying` keyword to communicate between vertex and fragment shader has been replaced by the more general `in`/`out` concpet, with which you can pass values to the next shader stage (in your program).
2. GLSL1.00 does not really exist. The first real version is 1.10. If you specify `#version 100`, you'll get GL **ES** SH 1.0 (which is native to GLES 2.0).
3. `gl_MultiTexCoord0` is a deprecated builtin, it will not be available in *core* profile / *core* version shaders. You should use generic vertex attributes for that.
4. GLSL in any version supports the builtin `gl_FragCoord` variable which will give you access to the screen-space coordinates of the fragment, so none of that stuff is really necessary. You might want the position in the range [0,1] (suitable for texturing), though, so using some texcoord attributes might still be the way to go. OTOH, just specifying the viewport size as a `uniform vec2` might still be more efficient, especially if you actually inverse it once on the CPU, so that this will boil down to one vector multiplication per fragment.

Comment: And here is the link to the documentation of `gl_FragCoord `: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml